# ¿Como usar variables en la configuración de host, username, password, port en PHPMailer para tener un solo archivo con esa información?

Tags: php, phpmailer

Tengo varios archivos diferentes que envían emails de formas diferentes con PHPMailer el problema es que si cambio la contraseña del usuario del SMTP el email el puerto etc... tengo que hacerlo en todos los archivos, entiendo que hay formas de reemplazar texto en archivos de forma progresiva pero yo quiero tener la configuración principal en un archivo separado para modificar este solo y sirva para todos usando include, y si el problema es de seguridad utilizaría sesiones.

Lo que no entiendo es si no funciona por seguridad o que estoy haciendo mal. Lo hago de la siguiente manera:

en un archivo `config_mail.php` defino las variables:

```
<?php
 //$smtpdebug=2;
 $host='smtp.servidor.com';                //Set the SMTP server to send through
 $smtpauth=true;                            //Enable SMTP authentication
 $username='email@example.com';               //SMTP username
 $password='password_aquí';                    //SMTP password
 $smtpsecure=PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;   //Enable implicit TLS encryption
 $port=465;                                 //TCP port to connect to; use 587 if you have set `SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS`
?>
```

Luego lo incluyo en cada archivo php que envía emails con phpmailer así:

```
require ('config_mail.php');
/* $host='smtp.servidor.com';                //Set the SMTP server to send through
 $smtpauth=true;                            //Enable SMTP authentication
 $username='email@example.com';               //SMTP username
 $password='password_aquí';                    //SMTP password
 $smtpsecure=PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;   //Enable implicit TLS encryption
 $port=465;  
*/
//Create an instance; passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            //Send using SMTP
    //$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
    $mail->Host       = $host;                   //Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = $smtpauth;                                   //Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = $username;                      //SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = $password;                           //SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = $smtpsecure;            //Enable implicit TLS encryption
    $mail->Port       = $port;                                    //TCP port to connect to; use 587 if you have set `SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS`
```

Con el include no funciona, si comento el include y descomento las variables en el archivo funciona.
¿Lo impide PHPMailer por seguridad? O ¿estoy haciendo allgo mal?

Comment: No se, ¿no da error en ninguna parte? ¿o que error te da?  Aparentemente parece correcto, a menos que el archivo config_mail.php no esté en ese path y no estes viendo el error.  Mira tambien en tu archivo de errores para ese dominio o pon un `error_reporting(E_ALL);` al principio del archivo para verlos.

Comment: El error está en la linea 7 del config_mail.php Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPMailer' not found in /var/www/html/config_mail.php:7 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/enviar_mensaje.php(118): require() #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/config_mail.php on line 7 osea en $smtpsecure=PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;   //Enable implicit TLS encryption

Comment: Pues comenta esa linea y no la modifiques en los otros archivos

Comment: llama a PHPMailer para encriptar y no está incluido en ese archivo entonces no puede seguir. Lo solucione poniendo solo esa linea en el archivo que envía email. $smtpsecure=PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS; Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Solución 1

Poner el `$smtpsecure=PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;` en el archivo que envía el email.